# How to test VS Code extensions use only .vsix as input artifact?

Tags: automated-tests, vscode-extensions

I'm super new in this field and I hope this is not a stupid question. Is it possible to test a VS Code extension without building it using the dev source code?
We are trying to develop a test automation framework of several extensions developed by our organization. The requirement is that we should **use only ".vsix" files** (which are packaged by the pipeline) for test.
I searched for several tools but they either require source code to build the extension or are not suitable in the case (I will provide detail later)

Mainly tried with 2 options:

1. vscode-extension-tester: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-extension-tester But this needs to build the extension
2. code-server: https://github.com/coder/code-server This one allows to install and run extensions in a browser instance of VS Code and turns everything to web GUI testing. However, it doesn't guarantee full identical behaviors between the browser instance and an actual one.

Comment: what did you end up using eventually? I have a similar use case.

Comment: Hey @HRD, I was wrong about my comments on the first method. In fact, it doesn't need the source code. The extension can be installed as a dependency. I will put the solution below so that it has better formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong about the first method (using the vscode extension tester). Users can use .vsix artifacts as dependencies.

We can start with using the "helloworld" sample provided: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-extension-tester/tree/main/sample-projects/helloworld-sample

Then modify "package.json", update the lines:

```
"install-vsix": "extest install-vsix -f {PATH_TO_VSIX} --extensions_dir .test-extensions",
"ui-test": "extest setup-tests --extensions_dir .test-extensions && npm run install-vsix && extest run-tests './out/ui-test/*-test.js' --code_settings settings.json --extensions_dir .test-extensions"
```

This allows users to work without building the extension. Then, all the work is about how to use the package. For more information, please refer to: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-extension-tester/wiki